# How input splits will get stored on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, block

For example we are having cluster of 4 machines. We want to store a file which got splitted into 6 input splits. Now my question is how these 6 input splits will be stored on cluster of 4 machines ?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify splits are logical divisions.
Blocks are physical divisions.
When a file is uploaded to hdfs, based on your blocksize setting which is 64mb(default) the file is divided into multiple blocks.

Based on your replication factor data is distributed among data nodes according to default block placement policy.

Hope this clarifies..